# SHOW/READ/READ-LINE/etc procedures on Scheme

Tags: lisp, scheme, procedure

I am learning Scheme and using some examples to see the stuff working.

I am using Chicken interpreter with Eclipse.

When trying to run the following code:

```
(define (bottles n)
  (if (= n 0)
      'burp
      (begin (verse n)
         (bottles (- n 1)))))

(define (verse n)
  (show (cons n '(bottles of beer on the wall)))
  (show (cons n '(bottles of beer)))
  (show '(if one of those bottles should happen to fall))
  (show (cons (- n 1) '(bottles of beer on the wall)))
  (show '()))

(bottles 3)
```

And I am getting the following error:

```
#;1> #;2>  Note: the following toplevel variables are referenced but unbound:

  verse (in bottles)
#;3> #;3>  Note: the following toplevel variables are referenced but unbound:

  show (in verse)   show (in verse)   show (in verse)   show (in verse)   show (in verse)

Error: unbound variable: show

Call history:

<syntax>      (bottles 3)   <eval>    (bottles 3)   <eval>    [bottles] (= n 0)     <eval>    [bottles] (verse n)   <eval>    [verse] (show (cons n (quote (bottles of beer on the wall)))) <--
```

Does anybody knows why? Of course if I create a procedure that says "show" will display stuff, then it works, but should SHOW be a standard procedure from Scheme? Because many codes through internet shows like that and there is no "show" procedure description. The same thing happens to READ/READ-LINE and etc.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not really into pokemons^W scheme, but was it `display` instead of `show`?

Comment: No, I got this example from here: http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~bh/ssch20/io.html

Comment: A quote from that chapter: "In fact, show isn't an official Scheme primitive; we wrote it in terms of display and newline."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `show` procedure is not defined. As part of the R5RS implemented in Chicken Scheme, you can use `display` or `write` for output, as shown in the [documentation](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/The%20R5RS%20standard#output).

The functionality of `show` can be easily implemented, though:

```
(define (show obj)
  (display obj)
  (newline))
```

Comment: What is the most complete Scheme interpreter?

Comment: @user1060551 that's a very, very subjective question, and it depends on what you understand with "complete". For learning purposes, I like DrRacket.

Answer (score 0):

Chicken's name for `show` is `print`.
If you do
`(define show print)`
you can use either name